# YouTube Data API is not enabled for Alpha testing, but it is enabled for development mode

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am getting below error for Alpha testing mode.

[Error]: Access Not Configured. The API(YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the google developers console to update your configuration.

But it works fine for developer mode. I have enabled the API on google developers console. I am missing something here? Do I need to change anything for production mode compared to developers mode? 
This is driving me crazy, I don't know a way to resolve this as Alpha testing mode does not have log writing, and it works perfectly fine on developers mode. I don't have a way to root cause this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved by enabling Auth Key for YouTube APIs